# Share parameter with dynamic build configure ID in teamcity

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a build chain with two jobs:  B depends on A. B needs to get a build counter from A. 
dep.btID.property name could share parameters from A to B.
**However, the btID is dynamic create by git for each branch**

I have add following to build steps of B(bash):

```
ABuildID=dep.dev_branch_A.env.BUILD_NUMBER
echo '%$ABuildID%'
```

or

```
echo '%${ABuildID}%'
```

It will lead to no compatible agent

Following could work however, I need to adapt to all branchs

```
echo '%dep.dev_branch_A.env.BUILD_NUMBER%'
```

Is there any way in TeamCity 9 to pass a build configuration parameter with **dynamic btID** from a project A to its dependency (in the same build chain)?

**---------------------Update after finding the solution, hope it will help someone in the future------------------------**

I have found a solution by request last successful build of projectA via rest api.

In bash:

```
  curl -s https://teamcity_host_name/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/dev_branch_A/builds?status=SUCCESS&state=finished&count=1
```

The response will provide the many parameter of project_A, build number is included

Please find introduction of teamcity rest API:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api.html#RESTAPI-URLStructure

Thanks Niraj Gajjar for the answser

Comment: Is "ABuildID" config.parameter ?

Comment: No,ABuildID is a variable in shell

Answer (score 0):

You have add **projectA** in **ProjectB** as either **Snapshot Dependency** or **Artifact Depedency** ( for that go to **Dependencies** from **left panel menu**)

After that you can use build counter of ProjectA like

```
%dep.ProjectA.build.counter%
```

**or**

```
echo %dep.ProjectA.build.counter%
```

Comment: I did, but not works. 
Currently, I have found a solution. 
I could get projectA's build number in response of https://teamcity_host_name/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/dev_branch_A/builds?status=SUCCESS&state=finished&count=1

Comment: IS ABuildID your shell param ?

Comment: No, it's just an variable that I am trying to generate dynamic btID for each branches

Comment: Have you tried using ABuildID=%dep.ProjectA.build.counter% ?

Comment: Yes, ABuildID=%dep.ProjectA.build.counter% woks. but the ProjectA is different for different branches. for example,btID of  master branch is master_ProjectA.

Comment: I understood your issue and you have resolved through API call, right ?

Comment: Yes, API call works. sound like nested parameters are not supported by teamcity